# PHP/posting a number as a string, intval can't convert it to a number

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm grabbing a number using jquery, from a piece of data in my html, as follows.

This is the html line.

```
echo "<p class = 'bold center remainingland' data-RemainingLandForFacilities = $RemainingLandForFacilities>Remaining Land For New Facilities : " . ($RemainingLandForFacilities) . "</p>";
```

I get the data using jquery with this...

```
var remainingland = $(this).closest('div').find('.remainingland').attr('data-RemainingLandForFacilities');
```

(after pressing a button, which is 'this'). This works correctly and an alert shows me the number.

I then post to my php script with the usual...

```
$.post('scripts/upgradefacility.php',
            {
                remainingland : remainingland
```

And I collect it with.

```
$RemainingLand = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'remainingland', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

At this point, I do have the number, but it's a string (as confirmed by gettype). But when I try to convert it to an integer with...

```
$RemainingLand = intval($RemainingLand);
```

I just get a blank. I should point out that I just copy/pasted all of this from previous variables which I'm passing, all of which come through correctly, so this is really odd. I can only assume that I've made some error that I can't spot or that I've been doing something wrong all along but I've somehow got away with it until now.

Comment: What is a "blank"?

Comment: intval doesn't return blank. It always returns an int, but defaults to 0 if it can't make the string an int. I'm guessing your output is screwing up. http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php

Comment: I output the result with die($result) and then put it into the console.log with my js. I'm just getting a blank. If I don't do the intval line, I'm getting the number (presumably still as a string when it arrives back at my js).

Comment: Die is just Exit, and exit responds differently to ints than it does strings. Please read the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: Ah ok, that's the problem. I wasn't aware of that, it just doesn't output integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't that `intval()` fails converting your data into an integer, your problem is you're returning it with `exit()`.

`exit()` takes one argument. If it's an integer, rather than printing it out, it uses it as an exit status code.

More information on how `exit()` works can be found in the php documentation here:-
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php